# Orange scaly thing in my Pilea's soil

Tags: identification

I've had this pilea for about 6 months, and when I was about to repot it I noticed this large orange scaly growth on one side of the plants soil. So far I have not found anything about what it is. Does anyone know?[image]

Comment: It could just be blur from the image, but it almost looks like there's some mold-looking fuzz on the left of the image on the top of the soil. Are you keeping it too wet? Did the water or pot smell like sulfur?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's one of the lichens such as Golden Eye, or maybe a liverwort, or it's possible but less likely the fruiting body of a fungus of some sort - hard to identify because its grown totally flat and is pale from being in the dark because of the pot. I wonder if it's Orange Cup fungus - those orange projections round the edges could be spores, but it seems more likely its lichen. If it is a fungus, the mycelium is present in the soil in the pot - as you're repotting, I would gently prise off the whole growth so as not to damage the roots of the plant, including the part just showing on top of the soil and then repot using new potting soil. Over time, it may recur though, but whatever the identity of the lichen/liverwort/fungus is, it's unlikely to be toxic to you or the plant, so long as you're not going to eat it. Make sure you use a clean pot with drainage holes and don't allow the plant to sit in water after watering - wet or damp soil will encourage these growths.